# Error compiling ns-3 waf (Could not load the Waf tool 'clang_compilation_database)

Tags: python, waf, ns-3

I update my ns-3 version (including private modules) to the last release and when compiling, this is the error generated:

```
mattia@pcsensori16:~/ns3-mmwave$ ./waf configure
Setting top to                           : /home/mattia/ns3-mmwave 
Setting out to                           : /home/mattia/ns3-mmwave/build 
Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : /usr/bin/gcc 
Checking for cc version                  : 4.8.4 
Checking for 'g++' (C++ compiler)        : /usr/bin/g++ 
Could not load the Waf tool 'clang_compilation_database' from ['/home/mattia/ns3-mmwave/.waf-1.8.12-f00e5b53f6bbeab1384a38c9cc5d51f7', '/home/mattia/ns3-mmwave', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
No module named clang_compilation_database
(complete log in /home/mattia/ns3-mmwave/build/config.log)
```

Someone has an idea about what I'm missing?

**[EDIT: add of the config.log file]**

```
Checking for 'clang++' (C++ compiler)
find program=['clang++'] paths=['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin', '/opt/local/bin', '/opt/local/sbin', '/usr/local/bin', '/usr/bin', '/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/sbin', '/opt/X11/bin', '/Library/TeX/texbin'] var='CXX' -> ['/usr/bin/clang++']
(tool ar is already loaded, skipping)
/usr/bin/clang++
from /Users/mattia/ns3-mmwave: Could not load the Waf tool 'clang_compilation_database' from ['/Users/mattia/ns3-mmwave/.waf-1.8.12-f00e5b53f6bbeab1384a38c9cc5d51f7', '/Users/mattia/ns3-mmwave/.waf-1.8.12-f00e5b53f6bbeab1384a38c9cc5d51f7/waflib', '/Users/mattia/ns3-mmwave', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
No module named clang_compilation_database
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove the build folder either manually (rm -f build) or with ./waf distclean and re-configure.

Comment: Hi Konstantinos, I tried what you suggest but still doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Which ns-3 release are you using and which OS? Have you checked the errata on [NS-3.24](https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/Ns-3.24-errata)? 
Can you also provide the complete log in /home/mattia/ns3-mmwave/build/config.log that has the complete error log?

Answer (score 0):

Super old, but still found this problem relevant today. In my wscript, with ns3 in particular, the tooldir is `waf-tools`, so you want to do something like:

```
def options(opt):
    opt.load('clang_compilation_database', tooldir='waf-tools')

def configure(conf):
    conf.load('clang_compilation_database', tooldir='waf-tools')
```

Found this useful for trying to setup clion with ns3: [How to setup CLion to use waf as build system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36941768/how-to-setup-clion-to-use-waf-as-build-system)